# how to change default database in codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I want to change my deafult database in my controller, but it doesn't change.

i'm doing this:

```
$this->db->close();

$config['default']['database'] = "second";

$this->load->database($config);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

config:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'test1';


//Another database connection.
$db['db2']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['db2']['username'] = 'root';
$db['db2']['password'] = '';
$db['db2']['database'] = 'test2';
```

controller:

```
// close the default connection
$this->db->close();
// connect to the other db
$this->db = $this->load->database('db2', true);
```